# merge columns in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I need help to merge 2 columns of array of struct type in pyspark.

The input columns are:

```
colA:
[
 {"itemType": "type1", "productCode": "prcd1", "productName": "pen"},
 {"itemType": "type2", "productCode": "Prcd2", "productName": "book"}
 ]



 colB:
 [
 {"city": "delhi", "country": "india"},
 {"city": "la", "country": "usa"}
 ]
```

[image]

and the expected output column(nth field of colA merged with nth field of colB) is:

```
colA-colB:
 [{"itemType": "type1", "productCode": "prcd1", "productName": "pen","city": "delhi", "country": "india"},
 {"itemType": "type2", "productCode": "Prcd2", "productName": "book","city": "la", "country": "usa"}]
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `withColumn` function with `udf` to create new column, like:

```
@udf(returnType=StringType())
def mergeColumns(col1, col2):
     result = dict(list(col1.items()) + list(col2.items())) //make one dict from two


df.withColumn("mergedData", mergeColumns("col1", "col2"))
```

Comment: Could you please help me to know what is result=col1[0]+col2[1] !!  Here we are expecting to add 0th element(struct type) of col1 to merge 0th element(struct type) of col2 and the result is an array of struct type.

Comment: You have a dictionary, not strict in python. And each row will now contain result of two dict merge. 

See answer edit. Filling each row with this udf (when you create new column) will be new column that is array of data. So udf describes how each cell should be created, and withColumn applies it to every row, so forms an array

Comment: Its throwing below error during invoking of udf function: PythonException: 'ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 7; 2 is required'

Comment: Below is the json data:
{
"colA":
[
 {"itemType": "type1", "productCode": "prcd1", "productName": "pen"},
 {"itemType": "type2", "productCode": "Prcd2", "productName": "book"}
 ],
 
"colB":
 [
 {"city": "delhi", "country": "india"},
 {"city": "la", "country": "usa"}
 ]
 }
Below code I have tried:
dfProd = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json("file path of the json file")

@udf(returnType=StringType())
def mergeColumns(col1, col2):
     result = dict(col1[0] +col2[0])
     return result

dfProd1=dfProd.withColumn("mergedData", mergeColumns("colA", "colB"))

Comment: It's a dictionary merge error, pleasse try updated version

Comment: with updated udf, now its throwing different error: 
PythonException: 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items''

Could you please run above code at your cluster and share me the snapshot of the output?

Comment: So you dta is not dictionary it is list. I am not quiet sure about you data structure, so can't help you further with exact merge expression, sorry

Comment: colA:array
 element:struct
 itemType:string
 productCode:string
 productName:string
colB:array
 element:struct
 city:string
 country:string

Above is the data structure and I have also updated the main thread with the schema. Any way, thanks for your effort. appreciate that.

Comment: ah, so it is pyspark struct type, so the answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72580180/spark-merge-two-columns-of-array-struct-type

Comment: the above solution wont work, as the column names (schema of both array) is different.

Comment: @blackbishop any idea about how that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the solution:

```
dfProd = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json("file path to json file")
dfProd1=dfProd.withColumn("mergedData", expr('transform(colA,(x,i)->struct(x.itemType,x.productCode,x.productName,colB[i].city,colB[i].country))'))
```